# Why is my bar chart not displaying (Chart.js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js2

I am trying to plot a bar chart in the HTML element with id="myChart", upon clicking **any** of the droplist options. I have to plot my x and y axis data based on an array input. Console shows nothing is wrong but no graph is displayed. My droplist is created with bootstrap3, chart with Chart.js version 2

Please assume for now that the same bar chart will be plotted no matter which droplist option the user clicks on. I just dont know why the bar chart is not displaying.

Current HTML code

```
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Retrieve Graph for Event 
                <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="generatedroplist">                      

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <canvas id="myChart" width="1" height="1"></canvas> 
            </div>
```

Current Javascript code

```
    //====== GENERATE DROPDOWN WITH BOOTSTRAP ========================
    var edonebutton = document.getElementById("eventdonebutton");
    edonebutton.onclick = function generatedroplist() {

    $('#generatedroplist').empty();                             

    var list = document.getElementById("generatedroplist");  //when click done button then populate
        for (var h = 1; h < numberOfEvents + 1; h++){                
            var opt = "Event " + h;         
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var link = document.createElement("a");             
            var text = document.createTextNode(opt);
            link.appendChild(text);
            //link.href = "#";
            li.appendChild(link);
            list.appendChild(li);
          }

}
      //========= CREATE BAR CHART ON CLICK OF ANY OPTION ================
            var xaxisarr = []; //global array
            var yaxisarr = []; //global array

            $('#generatedroplist li').on('click', function getgraph(){     

            xaxisarr = doublearrx[1];       //value in double array based on drop down list
            yaxisarr = doublearry[1];                               

            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: xaxisarr,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Workload Value',
                        data: yaxisarr,
                        backgroundColor: 
                            'rgba(244, 81, 30, 0.5)',  //change transparency here

                        borderColor: 
                            'rgba(244, 81, 30, 0.5)',

                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

The chart plots fine if I apply onclick on a separate link button instead of the droplist option as shown below.

Javascript code when onclick of link button

```
    var xaxisarr = []; //global array
    var yaxisarr = [];

    var retrievegraph = document.getElementById("retrievegraph"); 

        retrievegraph.onclick = function getgraph() {

                xaxisarr = doublearrx[1]; 
                yaxisarr = doublearry[1];

                var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: xaxisarr,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'Workload Value',
                            data: yaxisarr,
                            backgroundColor: 
                                'rgba(244, 81, 30, 0.5)',  //change transparency here

                            borderColor: 
                                'rgba(244, 81, 30, 0.5)',

                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero:true
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is why it's not working.  Since you are dynamically adding elements to your dropdown, you must attach your click event only after this is complete.

In your current code, you are binding a click handler to all dropdown elements (but none exist yet...or even if some do exist, you are later clearing them out when you do `$('#generatedroplist').empty()` and then are adding new).  As soon are you remove those DOM elements, the previously bound handler will no longer work.

The solution is pretty easy.  Just wrap your dropdown click binding function inside another function that you can call after you dynamically create the dropdown items.

```
var edonebutton = document.getElementById("eventdonebutton");

edonebutton.onclick = function generatedroplist() {
  $('#generatedroplist').empty();

  var list = document.getElementById("generatedroplist"); //when click done button then populate
  for (var h = 1; h < numberOfEvents + 1; h++) {
    var opt = "Event " + h;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var text = document.createTextNode(opt);
    link.appendChild(text);
    link.href = "#";
    li.appendChild(link);
    list.appendChild(li);
  }

  bindClickEvent();
};

var bindClickEvent = function() {
  $('#generatedroplist li').click(function(e) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Workload Value',
          data: data,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(244, 81, 30, 0.5)',
            //change transparency here
          borderColor: 'rgba(244, 81, 30, 0.5)',
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/wJpjoj) demonstrating this.

Comment: Hi, jordan. Thank you so much for replying. Yes, I have indeed dynamically generated my dropdown and had added that code above for you to view. Could you take a look again and let me know where the problem is?

Comment: Additionally, if I create ID for each dropdown item, the dropdown will have as many ids depending on how many items the user generated. Hence, if user clicks on item2 for example, the program should be able to automatically bind the click event based on the id set for that dropdown item 2.

Comment: You're awesome haha. It worked. Could I ask you if it is possible to only show one graph at a time? Eg. After clicking dropdown item1, a barchart appears, if I click dropdown item2, I want to remove the bar chart plotted for item1 and only plot the bar char for item2.

Comment: Does only the data change (e.g. labels and chart options stay the same)?

Comment: Yes, only the data changes. ^^

Comment: Jordan, sorry for the late reply. I was trying out the code but it does'nt seem to work for me. I must have misread what you meant by labels, both my x and y axis data does change for each event. This is my current code updated with your help.  console kept returning that "data is not defined" for the code that goes var chartData = data[$(currentTarget).data('id')] https://jsfiddle.net/7e26t55v/5/